# Cannot log in to the MySQL server after loging in in localhost using Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost, tomcat7

So here is the deal. I can connect to MySQL with my credential but when I run Tomcat 7 and then my web app in localhost:8080 at first I see that the app can "read" the db. When I try to log in though, after that, I **can't access my phpMyAdmin MySQL** with my credentials and I don't know why. Do you think is it from auto-creating some threads/connections??? OS:Win7

Comment: Could you show us your connection/pool jdbc configuration? without your sensitive data.  That will help us a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I can guess you are not closing/releasing connections on java.

Check how many concurrent connections you have open on mysql:

```
show processlist;
```

Also the maximum your mysql allows:

```
show variables like 'max_connections'
```

If you have too many concurrent connections, you should search where you are not closing or releasing connections in your code.